# Apache: Forbidden - You don't have permission to access /hello-world.php:10081 on this server

Tags: apache

Just taking very first steps in learning PHP/Apache, which hasn't started off too well. Wrote a hello-world script, but get a forbidden error message when I access it through the browser.

The URL I'm using is

```
http://localhost/hello-world.php:10081
```

and the file I write is at

C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\hello-world.php

What do I need to do to fix this?

The book I'm reading from doesn't say anything about this security issue, so this is why I've taken to a forum instead.

Now, as I say, I know nothing about apache and PHP (although I am an experienced software 
developer; just not web), so please take this into consideration when answering.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this url instead:

```
http://localhost:10081/hello-world.php
```

Are you sure your apache instance is running on port 10081? You can modify it in the httpd.conf file, on the **Listen** directive